# Template class as Stl container parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to use any STL container, for example `std::vector` with my own template type, for example `OptionParams`.

If i compile my code with empty main function - all Ok, but if i want print any field of my template class in container i have error. I'am not sure, that may be possible use in Stl container template class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct OptionParams {
    OptionParams(int level, int name, bool is_flag, T value) : level_(level), 
            name_(name), is_flag_(is_flag), value_(value) {}
    int level_;
    int name_;
    bool is_flag_;
    T value_;
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<OptionParams<T>> Options = {
    {OptionParams<int>(1, 2, 0, 3)},
    {OptionParams<std::string>(1, 2, 1, "hello")}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Options<int>[0].level_ << std::endl;
}
```

```
map2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::vector<OptionParams<int>, std::allocator<OptionParams<int> > > Options<int>’:
map2.cpp:23:16:   required from here
map2.cpp:17:30: error: could not convert ‘{{OptionParams<int>(1, 2, 0, 3)}, {OptionParams<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >(1, 2, 1, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"hello"), std::allocator<char>()))}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<OptionParams<int>, std::allocator<OptionParams<int> > >’
 std::vector<OptionParams<T>> Options = {
                              ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: All objects in a vector need to be of the same compile-time type. Use polymorphic objects with a common base class if you want to store different types of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Options` is a variable template which you can instantiate with a single parameter `T` to get a variable. When you do so with `Options<int>` in `main`, you end up with a `std::vector<OptionParams<int>>`, which can *only* store `OptionParams<int>`s, but not the `OptionParams<std::string>`. Since there is no possible conversion between different `OptionParam<T>`s, you get an error.

If you want to store heterogeneous objects inside an `std::vector`, you need some kind of type erasure. For example, have all specializations of `OptionParams<T>` inherit from a common base class, and store `std::unique_ptr`s to that base class.